# View as background on canvas using SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview

How to use View, created in another class, as background(non bitmap) for Canvas on SurfaceView?For example, I made Matrix in 1 class and would like to use it as background in another class which extends SurfaceView?I don't want to add whole Matrix to thread, as I don't want my canvas to repaint it every time thread updates.

```
Thread t=null;
SurfaceHolder holder;
boolean isRunning=false;
int x=200;

public ZmijicaSV(Context context) {
    super(context);
    holder=getHolder();
}

public void run()
{
    Paint p=new Paint();
    p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

     while(isRunning)
     {

         if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
             continue;
         }
         Canvas c=holder.lockCanvas();
         c.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
         c.drawRect(x,0,x+100,100,p);
         holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
         x+=10;

         try {
            t.sleep(500);

         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}

public void resume()
{
    isRunning=true;
    t=new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void pause()
{
    isRunning=false;
    while(true)
    {
        try {
            t.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    t=null;
}
```

Comment: Layering a SurfaceView Surface with Views can be tricky. A custom view (http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html) or TextureView can be easier to work with.